# How to display on-screen number pad instead of full keyboard in WPF desktop application?

Tags: c#, wpf

The task is simple. I have standard desktop Windows 10 application. It has a TextBox control. When it gets focus, I want only numbers to be allowed. It's easy to filter the keyboard input, but how to make the application display the number pad on touch devices?

I've read http://brianlagunas.com/showing-windows-8-touch-keyboard-wpf/ .
I have no use for described solution, my application depends on touch events, so I have no problem showing the on-screen keyboard manually. However - I have numeric input field and it's super user-unfriendly to show the user an on-screen keyboard where he or she can't even enter numbers directly.

I can't make this app on UWP, because it heavily depends on unmanaged, architecture-dependent DLL-s.